# Prove the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus without using $\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^cf(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_c^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I would like to see a proof of the following property, which Stewart calls $\mathbf{FTC 1}$ in his calculus books.

$\mathbf{FTC 1:}$ If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then the function $g$ defined by
$g(x)= \int_{a}^{x} f(t)dt$ for $a \le x \le b$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ , and $g'(x)=f(x).$

In particular, I would like to see a proof of $\mathbf{FTC 1}$ which does not use the property that $\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^cf(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_c^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx$. This is Property $5$ of integrals in Stewart's book. Let us call this property $(*)$ for short. Almost every proof I have seen of $\mathbf{FTC 1}$ begins with something like this:

Suppose we have $x$ and $x+h$ in $(a,b)$, then we have $g(x+h)-g(x)= \int_{a}^{x+h}f(t)dt-\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt =\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt+\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t)dt-\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt =\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t)dt$

Notice how we have used the property $(*)$ above. Some people have claimed we can prove $(*)$ using $\mathbf{FTC 2}$, that is

$\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = F(b) - F(a)$

where $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$. In my opinion, such an argument is fully justified only if we have already proved both $\mathbf{FTC 1}$ and $\mathbf{FTC 2}$ without using $(*)$. Perhaps we can approach $\mathbf{FTC 1}$ by considering $\dfrac{g(x) - g(a)}{x -a}$ instead of $\dfrac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}$ but I honestly do not know.

Comment: $\int_a^b f(t) \ dt  + \int_b^c f(t)\ dt = \int_a^c f(t) \ dt$ follows directly from the Reimann sum definition of the integral.  While this doesn't answer your question direction, it is valid to use it to prove these theorems rigorously.

Comment: I don't know why we use FTC2 to prove $(*)$. Any tagged partition of $[a,b]$ can be refined to a tagged partition that contains $c$, and we can prove $(*)$ from that.

Comment: Wikipedia has a rigorous proof that does not require the identity you cite.

Comment: @Angel Perhaps I am overlooking something, but it looks like the proof from Wikipedia does actually use the property $(*)$